# Refrigerator airflow dimensions not met

Tags: appliances

[image]

This is a side-view of the space for a prospective refrigerator I'm considering. The refrigerator has dimensions of 82.5cm x 72.8cm x 181.8cm (Width x Depth x Height). This refrigerator calls for 0.5cm of clearance on each side, 0.5cm behind, and 5cm on top. The width of my space is 92.5cm, so each side will have 5cm of space. The height of my space however is only 184.15cm because of the cabinet placement. So the airflow space will only be 2.35cm.

However as you can see, the cabinet isn't all the way back to the wall, so there is actually a 20.5cm x 66cm x 92.5cm empty space in the upper back. Does the bigger side space (an extra 4.5cm on each side) and extra space in the rear make up for the missing 2.65cm of clearance that the manufacturer says I need on top of the fridge? I'm thinking the extra vertical space in the back plus the generous side spaces should be more than enough to offset the 2.35cm space on top of the fridge itself, but I can't be sure. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Not doing what the instructions say, can have the warranty denied.  Talk to the makers and get it in writing that your space is okay, with the extra space on the sides.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't sweat it, but crip659 is probably "letter of the law" correct.

Comment: I've had the use of several refrigerators which had nowhere near the specified clearances, and never a problem. It would take actual thermal and performance measurements taken at your location to answer your question, all else is mere speculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the manufacturer puts those numbers on there is for airflow space suggestions. Allowing your condenser to breathe, and not get clogged with dust and lint so fast. If by your specs provided, you meet it on one side, and over compensate on the other though you should be fine.